# What should be the apt joining condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables of the following format:

Table 1:

```
Id1  Id2   Sent_Email    Date
123   22     1            24-Oct
234   11     1            24-Oct
```

Table 2:

```
Id1  Id2   Open_Email    Date
123   22     1           24 Oct
123   22     1           24 Oct
1234  01     1           24 Oct
```

On left joining table 1 with table 2 on the Id1 and id2
I am getting:

```
Id1  Id2   Open_Email  Sent Email  Date
123   22     1         1           24 Oct
123   22     1         1           24 Oct
```

What change should I make if I only want a single entry in my out for these?
Desired Output:

```
Id1  Id2   Open_Email  Sent Email  Date
123   22     1         1           24 Oct
```

Comment: use `select distinct ....`

Comment: Please show your "left join".  If don't correctly, you should have either id 234 or 1234 in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct` with `select` statement like below:

```sql
select 
distinct 
t1.id1, t1.id2, t1.open_email, t2.sent_email, date from 
table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id1=t2.id1 and t1.id2=t2.id2
```

Note: - As per sample data and output it seems a `inner join` instead of `left join`.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the duplicates from table2 before joining:

```
select t1.*, t2.open_email
from table1 t1 join
     (select distinct t2.id1, t2.id2, t2.open_email
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1 and t1.id2 = t2.id2;
```

I suspect this might optimize better than a `group by` after the `join`.